# UITextField placeholder has different font size

Tags: ios

I have a few textFields made in interface builder and then a few made programatically. The placeholder text seems to have different sizes. It seems I should be able to get the same font without subclassing UITextField. I am just trying to recreate the a textfield which looks like the one from interface builder.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.placeholder = string;
[textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
textField.inputAccessoryView = [[QEDCKeyboardAccessory alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
textField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: So what is your problem then .?

Comment: You can set textfield fontsize in code.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the textField?

Comment: I don't get how this is off topic. This maybe a very simple question but it is a programming question.

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao the "off topic" reason includes "questions that cannot be answered because we don't know what you've done so far" as well as "questions that are about non programming issues."

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao The question was closed because you didn't clearly show what was giving you trouble. It's got reopen votes since you added your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that, when you are about to `creation of UITextField via programmatically and IB, The Font size of UItextfield are different` .

```
You just need to set the Font size are Equal by IB as well as Programmatically,
```

> There is no separate font functionality for PlaceHolder

Comment: But we can set different font to the `textField `'s text ,right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by programmatically setting up the value for the key @"_placeholderLabel.font"

```
[self.input setValue:[UIFont fontWithName: @"American Typewriter Bold" size: 20] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
```

and also You can override drawPlaceholderInRect to do this....

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
         [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
}
```

Comment: [self.txtField setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];

Answer (score 1):

You can `set an attributed string on the placeholder`. If your interface builder text fields are using attributed strings it uses the same attributes, except for the foreground color.

See this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/attributedPlaceholder):

Answer (score 0):

They never have different size, thats the size of the textSize for UItextfield. Please check the size of TextSize from its property